# Gain of Yagi turnstile?

Tags: antenna-theory, satellites, yagi

I am currently working on a system to communicate with amateur CubeSats. I have decided to use the turnstile crossed-dipole style yagi because it is relatively easy to construct and uses circular polarization. However, I cannot find resources on how to calculate the gain for such an antenna. 
[image: Turnstile Yagi Antenna]

I suspect the gain would be equivalent to that of a typical yagi with the same characteristics. Is this correct?

Comment: Welcome to ham.stackexchange.com!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to calculating the gain of any antenna is usually to model it. EZNEC is a common solution.

Absent modelling, you are correct that a circularly polarized Yagi will have gain approximately equal to an similar linearly polarized one.